# Can I interact with .NET libraries through Javascript?

Tags: c#, .net, php, javascript

We've built a set of .NET libraries (in C#) which are used to interact with an outside resource. The outside resource provide bindings in Java and .NET, so it was necessary to build our libraries in one of those languages and we're officially a Windows shop.

We also use PHP/Javascript for a lot of our front-end web applications. Is it possible for these PHP/Javascript web applications to interact with our .NET libraries? We have both IIS and Apache web servers if that makes a difference. Communication would need to go in both directions.

Comment: If you are talking about javascript running in a web browser, then you just described every single AJAX app written in .NET. If you're talking about calling .NET assemblies from JS which is being run on a server via the Windows Scripting Host, then please let us know.

Comment: The question was 'HOW' javascript can 'talk' to C# dlls. I was hoping that there would be a way without using web services. Though I suppose we can write web methods to expose the same functionality and run them on each server that runs an application using them to minimise delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most obvious approach is exposing your .NET libraries [as web services](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/010430.htm) on a web server (either IIS or Apache/Mono). This allows both JS and PHP to consume the same service endpoints (JS via AJAX, PHP vs web service calls).

If extreme performance is a concern - for example, your PHP apps need to make heavy calls into the .NET libraries as if they are native, then web services are probably not the best  approach. For that, you might want to look into making [COM Callable Wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx) for your .NET libraries and [consuming them from PHP](http://dev.juokaz.com/winphp-2009/using-php-with-c-written-libraries).

Answer (score 2):

Although Ajax is the usual approach, another idea for you, in case it might help, would be to use Silverlight on the client side.  That way, you would embed your .NET classes into a Silverlight application, which would then be downloaded to the client where it would run inside the browser.  Silverlight apps can easily interact bi-directionaly with JavaScript, as well as with remote resources.

For example, you can mark a .NET method with the `[ScriptableMember]` attribute, which will expose it to JavaScript.

Comment: I do somewhat like this idea, yet the reason I asked about PHP is because we have a number of PHP developers that we could leverage.

Comment: Using Silverlight would mean offloading your servers and pushing some of the logic into the client.  You could still use PHP to build your web pages; the two technologies are compatible (you can even serve a Silverlight app from Apache; it doesn't require IIS).

With PHP+Ajax only is that you would still need to build a web services wrapper for your .NET libraries on the server. That ties you to Windows on the server side (not necessarily a bad thing), and doesn't eliminate the need to still write some new .NET code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data via AJAX calls where you communicate to and from the client via JSON.  For client side data set manipulation [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq) is a great library for performing Linq queries on JSON objects.

If you are looking for a good place to start with web services, JSON and ASP.Net webforms Dave Ward's [posts on Encosia](http://encosia.com/2009/07/21/simplify-calling-asp-net-ajax-services-from-jquery/) are really top notch.